# Risk in using isset?

Tags: php, sanitization

I am new to PHP.

I have been advised to sanitize `$_GET` and `$_POST`.  I have been following this advice.

However, if I just want to check the variable with

```
if(isset($_GET['login']))
```

do I need to do any sanitization on that?

Also, do I need to sanitize `$_SESSION` values I use?

Comment: you only need to sanitize the code if you are putting it to the database

Comment: @Raymond Ho: not only to a database, but to any kind of storage/device which accepts some special form of input data.

Comment: @RaymondHo: Not true. There are a few other attack vectors that require input data sanitization (e.g. XSS).

Comment: @Raymond, what about using it in exec or something? or as dynamic value for an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you do not have to do any kind of sanitization or anything : [**`isset()`**](http://fr.php.net/isset) will allow you to check if the variable *(or item array, in your case)* exists -- and that's pretty much it.

Here, as you are testing whether the item/variable exists or not, you cannot sanitize it : to sanitize the data, you need it to exist.

Note, though : `isset()` will return `false` if that item exists, but is `null` !

*Which, in the case of a `$_GET` item, will quite not probably happen.*

Comment: will quite probably not happen? why?

Comment: @David19801: because every value that comes from $_GET is a **string**, without any exceptions.

Comment: @David create a php script that just contains `var_dump($_GET);` and try getting it to display something `null` -- you'll see ;-) *(humph, zerkms has been faster than me ^^ )*

Comment: @nikic: oh, great catch. I wish I could make a bounty for your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No. If you just want to check whether variable exists or not - then your code is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no risk in doing that.

Sanitization is required before you proceed to use the values in `$_GET`/`$_POST` in your business logic (e.g. building database queries with it or displaying it to the user as part of your HTML output); here you are just testing if a value exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. But better way to do this would be:

```
if(key_exists('login',$_GET)) {
}
```

Comment: If the key is set but is null, than isset returns false, as Pascal said.

Comment: Not better at all. It might be more appropriate if $_GET could contain `null` values, but it cannot.

Comment: @Tomáš Plešek: Actually I am pretty sure that `array_key_exists` does exactly that, testing `isset($array($key))`, so array_key_exists could actually be slower due to the additional function call.

Comment: @Tomáš Plešek: the data that comes from $_GET is always presented as string. So there is no possible way to pass `null` there.

Comment: @x3ro: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php [example #2].

Comment: It can if you put something there, either by accident, code, framework or something along those lines. But yes, it will be solwer than isset, that's good observation.

Comment: @Tomáš Plešek: if your framework modifies the superglobals to pass some data - you definitely made a wrong decision when chose a tool. It is a good moment to rethink and choose another one ;-)

Comment: As x3ro pointed out, `array_key_exists` does indeed behave differently from `isset` in the case of null values, but as Tomáš pointed out, this difference is not relevant here, as the $_GET array will not have null values.

Comment: @zerkms oh well, right, but that's not the point. It's just that the possibility of modyfiyng a superglobal exists, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Tomáš Plešek: indeed, it is. Never seen that in real life though.

Comment: I actually did, and that's why i posted the answer (and yes, that was terribly poor design). Sometimes it's not possible to change entire framework or application, even if you wanted to , and you just have to work with whatever is thrown at you. But that's for another discussion

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for sanitation, if you need only to check if the key login is setted, it is better to doing so:

`if(array_key_exists('login',$_GET))`

Because if the key is not setted your code will throw a notice error.